# How to assert a javascript/ client side validation message in phpunit with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am running phpunit tests on my symfony. i am able to assertExp of failed test with message from server side but how can i test the message for client side(javascript message)

```
$this->assertRegExp('/1 country\/countries removed successfully/', parent::$client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

Here the message "1 country/countries removed successfully" is a server side message but i need certain client side messages to get validated such as for empty field validation.

Comment: [You cannot test javascript with PHPUnit](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/28309). However, you can test the controller action and its returned content

Comment: my whole website is almost based on JavaScript. Is there any other way to test the validations.

Comment: Use a library that's designed to unit test JavaScript code. Sinon.js, Jasmine (BDD), and QUnit seem to be popular.